# ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Lucas_Johnson' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I am trying to insert into a MySQL database and it is giving me the error:

```
ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Lucas_Johnson' in 'field list'
```

The command is:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO master (ID, Name, Location, DateTime, Status, flagged) VALUES("+str(id)+","+str(name)+","+place+","+date.replace(':','-').replace(' ', '_')+", 'Out', "+str(flagged)+")")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are lacking proper quotes in your SQL string. You could print the string before executing it, then you would see it.

But you don't use the proper methods to do it. This way, you compose the SQL string in a very SQL-injection-prone way.

The correct way of doing it is

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO master (ID, Name, Location, DateTime, Status, flagged) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (id, name, place, date.replace(':','-').replace(' ', '_'), 'Out', flagged)
```